# If..begin..begin tran..Rollback

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've following code but it gives an error, please guide me how to nested if..begin..begin__tran__Rollback or commit

```
declare @acname as varchar(max),
    @gstcount as int

set @acname='Party1'

use TESTDB

set @gstcount = (select count(GSTIN) from M_STATEWISEGSTINACTAG where GSTIN<>'UNREGISTERED' AND ACCD=
(select accd from m_ledger where descr LIKE @acname))


if @gstcount = 1 
   begin 
    --multiple select statments 
    select .......
    --to display require info.
   end

 --Then Update Values
     begin tran;
       update M_tbl ........where....

    --Show result with updated value
       select * from M_tbl........where.........

    --Undo Changes
      ROLLBACK; 
else
 begin
      SELECT ........reuqir info

 end;
```

In this script I got an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.

Comment: I check with end, end;,  end tran, end tran; still it gives me an error on same line number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @acname AS VARCHAR(MAX), @gstcount AS INT;
SET @acname = 'Party1';
USE TESTDB;
SET @gstcount =
(
    SELECT COUNT(GSTIN)
    FROM M_STATEWISEGSTINACTAG
    WHERE GSTIN <> 'UNREGISTERED' AND ACCD =(SELECT accd FROM m_ledger WHERE descr LIKE @acname)
);
IF @gstcount = 1
    BEGIN
        BEGIN 
    --multiple select statments 

            SELECT .......
    --to display require info.
       END;

 --Then Update Values
        BEGIN TRAN;
          update M_tbl ........where....
    --Show result with updated value
          select * from M_tbl........where.........
    --Undo Changes
        ROLLBACK TRAN;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT........reuqir info;
    END;
```